# Read data from word document in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word

I have a requirement to read/parse data collected inside a word document using ASP.NET / C#. I need to store the collected data (not the word document) inside a rational database.  The word document has checkbox and drop down controls to capture the data.

I have access to the word document so I can update the document to add any extra tag/hints if required.

[image]

Is it possible to parse a word document using .Net?

Comment: Which version(s) of Word?

Comment: You may take a look at [free spire.doc for .net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FreeSpire.Doc/) nuget package, here is the [documentation](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.Doc/Spire.Doc-Program-Guide/Spire.Doc-Program-Guide-Content.html) for your reference. Disclaimer: I work for spire.

Answer (score 0):

Install the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` nuget [package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word?view=word-pia).